# Getting "dtype: float64," flags within an array filtered from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am doing a simple operation of computing distances between a point and coordinates in a pandas dataframe column as:

```
 d = np.sqrt( (xcoord - matches['X'][match_ind])**2 + 
              (ycoord - matches['Y'][match_ind])**2 +
              (zcoord - matches['Z'][match_ind])**2 )
```

and appending d values to an existing variable:

```
dist.append(d)
```

When I look inside the dist variable, I find:

```
[49.59627002077358,
 50.22857752296009,
 50.86088870622201,
 51.587401562727706,
 52.21972807281059,
 52.81865200841202,
 380047    51.375967
 380047    50.509999
 dtype: float64,
 380048    50.745739
 380048    50.918170
 dtype: float64,
 380049    50.115566
 380049    51.330887
 dtype: float64,
 380050    49.388258
 380050    51.748043
 dtype: float64,
 380051    48.758179
 380051    52.169531
 dtype: float64,
 380052    48.128162
 380052    52.595247
 dtype: float64,
 380053    47.400949
 380053    53.025088
 dtype: float64,
 380054    46.771038
 380054    53.458956
 dtype: float64,
 380055    46.141196
 380055    53.896753
 dtype: float64,
 380056    45.414095
 380056    54.338384
 dtype: float64,
 380057    44.784372
 380057    54.783757
 dtype: float64,
 380058    44.154728
 380058    55.232780
 dtype: float64,
 43.42775610155422,
 42.798247627814156,
 42.168827349210005,
 41.4420076734098,
...]
```

Does anyone know why dtype flags are included in the array? they should be just floats like rest of the array elements.

EDIT: I realised that this is because I have nonunique indices in my matches dataframe:

```
Distance    Z   Vp (m/s)    X   Y
380047  2392.916117 210.1   699.519104  257398.7    7303796.2
380047  2490.839096 209.2   604.929199  257491.6    7303781.9
```

not sure why that is the case though.

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like some of the time you're appending an array, not a float.

Comment: not sure what that should be because I am iterating the matches dataframe one index ("match_ind") at a time. So, d should be just one element.

Comment: I realise that this happening because my matches dataframe has nonunique indices, not sure why that is happening:

Distance Z Vp (m/s) X Y
380047 2392.916117 210.1 699.519104 257398.7 7303796.2
380047 2490.839096 209.2 604.929199 257491.6 7303781.9

Answer (score 0):

Problem is duplicated index values like `380047`, so instead `float`s get `Series`s.

Possible solution is create `mean`s for `Series`:

```
dist.append(d.mean() if isinstance(d, pd.Series) else d)
```

Another solution is remove duplicated indices before your solution:

```
matches = matches[~matches.index.duplicated()]
```

Better is get all indices in one final list, so possible remove final loop:

```
all_index = []

for i in iter:
   all_index.append(match_ind)
   
matches = matches[~matches.index.duplicated()]

dist = np.sqrt( (xcoord - matches.loc[all_index, 'X'])**2 + 
                (ycoord - matches.loc[all_index, 'Y'])**2 +
                (zcoord - matches.loc[all_index, 'Z'])**2 ).tolist()
```

Comment: sorry this doesn't work. 
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Comment: @januka - So my answer was helpfull?

Comment: thanks, but I used something simpler.

Answer (score 0):

**This is very simple.**

```
dist_values = dist.values.astype(float)
print(dist_values)
```

The Pandas Series format includes dtype flags that display the data type (float64) of the items. Due to adding d items from a DataFrame, the Series comprises elements with various indices, producing a mixed index representation. Access dist.values to get a NumPy array that contains only the float values.

Comment: sorry this doesn't work.
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: Use .astype(float) . OK . I am editing my answer. If any problem ? just comment .

Comment: Thanks! That still does not work primarily because I am re-writing the dist array in a for loop, where it appears that in all other iterations dist is a list except in this iteration where a mix type of arrays are created. I am iterating matches index by index and I am not sure why that process would create a list per iteration, making dist with mix classes.

Comment: I realised that my matches dataframe has the same index for two inputs:, not sure why that should be:
380047    257398.7
380047    257491.6
Name: X, dtype: float64

Comment: my answer was helpfull?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my edit, the issue was having nonunique indices in my matches dataframe. I fixed this by simply resetting the indices:

```
matches = matches.reset_index()
```

Thanks everyone for chipping in!